# Como centrar el texto en textArea

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap

tengo una tabla que se vizualiza en un modal y la columna descripcion_Recomendacion contiene textos bien extensos asi que usa el TextArea pero no entiendo porque me sale un espacio adelante de todo el texto ya en aplicado la clase `text-justify` tengo el siguiente codigo

```
                        <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
                          <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderRecomendacion[0] }}</th>
                                <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderRecomendacion[1] }}</th>
                                <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderRecomendacion[2] }}</th>
                                <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderRecomendacion[3] }}</th>
                                

                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr *ngFor="let rows of ListaRecomendacion">
                                <td class="text-center">{{rows.inciso}}</td>
                                <td class=" text-left ">
                                  <textarea class="form-control  text-left " placeholder="Descripcion Recomendacion" rows="4" name="Recomendacion" #Recomendacion [disabled]="Deshabilitar">
                                    
                                    {{rows.descripcion_Recomendacion}}
                                 </textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                  {{rows.fecha_Implantacion | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                  {{rows.estado_Vigencia}}
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
```

al momento de visualizar el modal me sale de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que este [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413143/justify-and-center-textarea-text-html-css) te puede ayudar

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo con el problema